How can i make a template a default template? Mapfish
Perhaps its a simple question:
The response of request GET /apps.json is the list of available print templates. The request always provides a default value.
E.g.
Response
[
"map",
"A4 map",
"A3 map",
...,
"default"

How can i make a template a default template ? How to define this in config.yaml?
